# gRPC generated python script fails to find a local module in the same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc-python

I have the following structure in my Python project:

```
main.py
sub1/
  __init__.py
  foo.py
  bar.py
  grpc_generated_pb2.py
  grpc_generated_pb2_grpc.py
```

I have been using the following approach to import local modules, for example,

```
(in sub1/foo.py)

from sub1 import bar
from sub1 import grpc_generated_pb2_grpc
```

It works. But now gRPC generated files do the following:

```
(in sub1/grpc_generated_pb2_grpc.py)

import grpc_generated_pb2 as grpc_generated_pb2
```

And Python fails to import the module with this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grpc_generated_pb2'`

Because it's generated code, I cannot/shouldn't modify it. My question is: why Python cannot import a local module under the same directory without doing `from sub1` ?

I think Python should always be able to import a local module from the same directory with a simple `import <module_name>` (no parent package names). Why doesn't it do that?

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out by others, there are already similar questions like this one: [How do I import from a file in the current directory in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269437/how-do-i-import-from-a-file-in-the-current-directory-in-python-3) .  However, my question is different in this sense:

Does it mean Google gRPC `grpc_tools.protoc` failed to generate a working file for Python 3?  I am adding gRPC tag hoping to get opinions from gRPC side. Thanks.

Comment: As a side not, you don't need to write `import grpc_generated_pb2 as grpc_generated_pb2`. It's repetitive. Just write `import grpc_generated_pb2`.

Comment: @MichaelKolber this code was generated by `grpc_tools.protoc`.  I didn't write it and   cannot/should not edit it.

Comment: If I understand PEP 328 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) correctly, `protoc` should really generate the import line like `from . import grpc_generated_pb2`, but why gRPC didn't do that?  (or should I put them under `sys.path` ?)

Comment: I found a good answer on GitHub: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9575#issuecomment-293934506 . Just to share here.