# Why can't I import a python file from the same folder into a project?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror

Why can't I import a file that I have in the same folder as the code I want to import? I am working in Visual Studio Code.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import webbrowser
import credentials
from pprint import pprint

r = requests.get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/favourites",
                 headers=credentials.headers)

try:
    content = r.json
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print("Wrong format")
else:
    pprint(content)
```

This is the problem the tab pops up.

```
Import "credentials" could not be resolved
```

And this is the content of the imported file.

```
headers = {"x_api_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Comment: Can you post the *full* and *exact* error message? It usually has more information, like which line is raising the error. Because that doesn't look like the standard import errors from Python. And what is "*tab*" in "*the tab pops up*"?

Comment: Try `import .credentials`.  In Python 3, imports are absolute by default, and you need to add '.' to them to make them relative (in this case, to the current dir). - I expect that you're using some sort of syntax checker, maybe because VSC has set that up.  That error is coming from the checker, I. believe, rather than the Python interpreter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import from a file in the current directory in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269437/how-do-i-import-from-a-file-in-the-current-directory-in-python-3)

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file?

Comment: All the above answers have to sense. When two files are in the same folder they can be imported without being any problem. The problem here is the name of the file.

Comment: Mate I think you have written the wrong file name. Try changing the name and then importing. I used VS Code itself and this is the error which I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this

> This is the problem the tab pops up.
>
> ```
> Import "credentials" could not be resolved
> ```

isn't an error coming from the Python interpreter, because it does not look like the standard "*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XXX'*", which is what you get when you *run* your Python code and your imports are wrong or misconfigured.

Since you mentioned Visual Studio Code and a "*tab*", then I'm guessing that's coming from an [integrated linter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) and it's displaying that error in the **Problems** tab:

[image]

If `credentials` is indeed in the *same directory* as that file, and you are running your code under the *same directory*, then

```
import credentials
```

should be fine. The problem is only with the linter, it does not know where to look for `credentials`. Depending on which linter you have enabled (see the [Linting Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) section of the docs), you'll have to *explicitly* tell your linter where to find `credentials`.

For example, assuming you have a folder `app` that contains `credentials` and this script:

```
app
├── ...(other files)...
├── credentials.py
└── script.py
```

Add/update a *.vscode/settings.json* file on your workspace (see the [General linting settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_general-linting-settings) section of the VS Code docs). I'm using [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) so I need to add a `python.analysis.extraPaths` list entry like this:

```json
"python.analysis.extraPaths":[
    "/absolute/path/to/app"
]
```

to basically tell my linter that "*when checking imports, also check this `app` folder*". That clears the "could not be resolved" from the Problems tab.