# Python can't find submodule in imported module

Tags: python, path, package

I'm trying to run a script ***test1.py*** which calls ***model.py***. However I encounter an import error when Python tries to import ***module.py*** from within ***model.py***. How can I get test1.py to find this?

```
├── model
├     ├── model.py
├     └── module.py
└─── tests  
      └── test1.py
```

***In test1.py***

```
from model.model import blah
```

***In model.py***

```
import module
```

When I run test1.py, Python complains that it can't see module.py:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'
```

FYI I am working in Python3

Comment: try `import .module`

Comment: Potentially duplicated by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269437/how-do-i-import-from-a-file-in-the-current-directory-in-python-3

Comment: The solution in that link isn’t applicable here

Answer (score 0):

You have to try like this `import .model`

or you have to add `__init__.py` file inside your `model` directory.

Here you go for python docks for `__init__.py`

> Python defines two types of packages, regular packages and namespace packages. Regular packages are traditional packages as they existed in Python 3.2 and earlier. A regular package is typically implemented as a directory containing an __init__.py file. When a regular package is imported, this __init__.py file is implicitly executed, and the objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace. The __init__.py file can contain the same Python code that any other module can contain, and Python will add some additional attributes to the module when it is imported.

I copied the docs from here: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: Adding an init file didn’t solve the problem. Nor did replacing model.model with .model